# How to query a graphql api that runs in another port?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am using a graphQL api that runs on localhost 3001, and I have a react app that I run with webpack-dev server that runs by default on localhost 8080.

The graphQl api is based on this server: https://github.com/marmelab/json-graphql-server

Normally to consume an api, you go to some url like:

`https://example.com/users/`

But this graphQl server is direclty on `localhost:3001`

And my react app runs on port `8080`.

How can fetch the api on port `3001`

I tried using fetch and passing the port 3001 as url but i get an error:

`GET http://localhost:3001/ 400 (Bad Request)`

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

a couple of questions,

Is it ok to have webpack dev server running on 8080 and the graphql server on another server(3001)

And if so, how can I hit that port from my react app?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting the whole URL? I.e., `http://localhost:3001/graphql`? Note that the GraphQL server will need to allow CORS requests from `localhost:8080`...

Comment: Thanks, that helped.. but now i get the error:  GET http://localhost:3001/ 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: That's between you and the server :). I don't know how the GraphQL server is setup or what it expects. I'm guessing you have to query for something.

Comment: hey @HereticMonkey if you add your first comment as anwer ill aprove it! thx